# Train an image classification model using Tesnsorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, training-data, resnet

what image classification to use for training?

we want to train a model with our own pictures for a school project. Can I use resnet50 or any other trainable model? I couldn't find Resnet50 trainable model and I found only pre-trained resnet50 model. We are using Tensorflow 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use the pre-trained Resnet. Load the keras version of resnet with weights=None and train the model yourself.

Comment: can you please point me to kera's version of resnet50...